# ¿Sería "la pescadilla que se muerde la cola" una buena traducción para "catch-22"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, inglés

Anteriormente en este sitio se ha preguntado [cuál sería una buena traducción para *catch-22*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18599/12637). Pues resulta que ayer mismo en el trabajo un compañero mío descubrió la expresión por primera vez, no la conocía y le explicamos que venía del título de un libro y que la expresión se había hecho lo suficientemente famosa como para estar recogida en el diccionario:

> **[catch-22](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch-22)**
>
> an impossible situation where you are prevented from doing one thing until you have done another thing that you cannot do until you have done the first thing

Viendo esa definición me acordé inmediatamente de la expresión española *la pescadilla que se muerde la cola* (de uso al menos en España, ignoro si en Hispanoamérica se usa), que a mi entender significa que no puedes resolver un problema hasta solucionar otro, cuya solución depende del primer problema. Iba a añadirla como respuesta a aquella pregunta. Sin embargo, me he encontrado con que nuestro diccionario la recoge así:

> [**la**, o **una**, **pescadilla que se muerde la cola**](https://dle.rae.es/pescadilla)
>
> 1. f. coloqs. Argumentación defectuosa que nada prueba, sino que vuelve al punto de partida.

Esta definición me ha despistado, porque no sé si define lo mismo que la expresión en inglés. Buscando su uso me he encontrado [el siguiente texto](https://expresionesyrefranes.com/2007/12/18/la-pescadilla-que-se-muerde-la-cola/):

> Seguro que en cuanto os ponga algún ejemplo lo veis más claro. Por ejemplo: el transporte de mi ciudad es la pescadilla que se muerde la cola: como casi nadie lo usa, es muy caro y como es muy caro, casi nadie lo usa (como veis, es un problema que así, de repente, no tiene solución porque los dos factores críticos en el transporte, el precio y el volumen de gente que lo utiliza, están relacionados entre sí).

Este ejemplo a mi entender se parece más a la definición de *catch-22*: aparentemente existen dos problemas cuyas soluciones dependen del otro problema. ¿Se puede entender también como una argumentación defectuosa que te devuelve al punto de partida, como dice la RAE? ¿O la definición de la RAE se refiere a otro tipo de situación? ¿Sería *la pescadilla que se muerde la cola* pues una buena traducción para *catch-22*?

Comment: _Pescadilla que se muerde la cola_ es solo en España, en el resto del mundo hispanohablante es _el pez que se muerde la cola_.

Comment: Both your suggestion and that of @Danielillo sound more like equivalents of _vicious circle_ to me. The definition of catch-22 in the question to which you link is much better than the one you quote unless its meaning has become extended over time.

Answer (score 2):

Considero que la frase está cerca, pero no es cabalmente fiel

> la pescadilla que se muerde la cola

es buena para designar la naturaleza circular y repetitiva de un problema (por el imposible de que el cuerpo se moviliza hacia su propia extremo, que al correrse vuelve inasible el objetivo)

Pero en mi opinion no hace suficiente, honor a la complejidad paradójica de la expresión catch-22

Lo de la pescadilla —al menos en Argentina, no se si también en Latinoamérica— se conoce como `un perro que se muerde la cola` y trae una imagen gráfica de algo inacequible. Pero, me parece, *se queda corta como figura para captar la escencia sutil, paralizante, de imposibilidad contradictoria y absurda* que aquella porta*.

Entiendo que sería muy dificil representar el disparate esencial, el imposible lógico de situaciones de tipo catch-22. Pensando en esto, se me viene otra imágen ridícula (para la cual no hay frase armada) de *alguien que infructuosamente intente empujar una camioneta para arrancarla haciendo fuerza parado sobre su caja (la parte trasera e interior de la misma)*.

[image: representacion del absurdo imposible de la trampa-22]

El espíritu capcioso de la regla de `catch-22` (exponer en vuelos de guerra constantes a las personas del escuadrón, con excepción de los locos, y al mismo tiempo negar cualquier diagnostico de insanía como impedimento, por entender que la resistencia a volar en esas misiones era por si misma una demostración de cordura) es paralelo al sinsentido (sin salida), en el que resultaria ***obligar a alguien a empujar una camioneta desde su interior, pudiéndo ser relevado de la tarea sólo cuando logre moverla***, algo intrínsicamente imposible.

Answer (score 1):

¿Se puede entender también como una argumentación defectuosa que te devuelve al punto de partida, como dice la RAE? ¿O la definición de la RAE se refiere a otro tipo de situación? ¿Sería la pescadilla que se muerde la cola pues una buena traducción para catch-22 ?

---

[image]

*Uróboro*

El **uróboro**  puede simbolizar varias cosas, así puede significar el ciclo eterno de las cosas, también el esfuerzo  y la lucha eterna, pero también el esfuerzo inútil, ya que el ciclo regresa para comenzar pese a los gestos para frenarlo.

La misma imagen expresa la intención de vuelta al punto de partida que es la recogida por la RAE, pero la metáfora del dicho es algo más amplia y también recoge conceptos populares. Así podemos entender aquello que dada la forma circular de su representación, es algo que no tiene fin ni principio, pues su fin vuelve a convertirse en su principio, por otra parte se puede entender referente a que son dos cosas contrarias que se dan a la vez, por lo que de ello se deriva la idea de su incongruencia o imposibilidad y por tanto la idea de lo absurdo que puede llegar a ser algo, esto lleva a su vez, al razonamiento de estar en una situación en la que igualmente no hay salida aparente ante ese problema, pues se convierte en algo cíclico del que no se puede escapar.

Estas consideraciones son recogidas desde la antigüedad en obras iconografías y otros mitos, apareciendo en español como expresiones sinónimas para el mismo dicho "**La pescadilla que se muerde o come la cola**". De esta manera para expresar la misma idea decimos, "*Uróboro*", "*El Mito o la roca de Sísifo*", "*La madeja de Penélope*", "*Dialelo*", "*Aporía circular*", "*Círculo Vicioso*", "*La historia del nunca acabar*", "*Banda o Anillo de Möbius*", "Paradoja"... que aunque con matices y características propias expresan esa misma idea general, utilizándose por una parte como sinónimo para referirse a "La pescadilla que se muerde la cola" y a la vez introduciendo en ella alguno de los conceptos más antiguos y amplios a los que ya he aludido y que la RAE no recoge de manera clara, aunque si son conocidos y utilizados popularmente.

Por tanto, ¿Sería la pescadilla que se muerde la cola pues una buena traducción para catch-22 ? **Por supuesto que sí**, pero también cualquiera de los conceptos anteriores servirían para expresar lo mismo.

En mi viejo diccionario de inglés dentro del epígrafe **catch**, aparece la expresión **catch-22 situation** y la define como situación de callejón sin salida, círculo vicioso.

Intentando saber más de este tema, busco el libro y encuentro que la traducción en español del libro **Catch-22** es "**Trampa**", calificando al libro como un "**Monumento al absurdo**".

En libro el autor, "Heller" se deleita en la paradoja y utiliza los personajes con razonamiento circular;

> El tejano resultó ser bonachón, generoso y simpático. En tres días
> nadie lo soportaba".
>
> El caso contra Clevinger estaba abierto y cerrado. Solo faltaba algo
> para acusarlo.

[image]

Un **Catch-22** es "*un problema para el cual la única solución es negada por una circunstancia inherente al problema o por una regla*". Así por ejemplo, un **Catch-22**, seria el caso de perder las gafas y no poder ver para buscarlas. Alguien no encuentra un trabajo por no tener coche para ese trabajo y no puede comprarlo por no tener trabajo. Este seria el caso típico de "***La pescadilla que se muerde la cola***".

Sin embargo, el término **Catch-22**, como en español, también se utiliza de una manera más amplia para referirse a un problema más complejo, una situación absurda, sin solución o que no tiene salida.

En este sentido, es fácil comprender el sentido al que nos ha conducido a la expresión  **Catch-22** como título del libro, ya que "**Catch**", en inglés también puede significar, según los contextos, "trampa" o "trampa sin salida" y por tanto, el concepto es una situación en la que hay una trampa o con trampa, en la que existe truco, una pillada o cogida. "*La trampa que lleva consigo la paradoja*".

Por lo visto entre los distintos títulos barajados, pues el primer capitulo publicado en 1955 fue como Catch-18, y tras varias vicisitudes sugirió el título de Catch-11, con el "uno" duplicado debido a la repetición que se encuentra en varios personajes de la novela, para por último elegir **Catch-22**, que igualmente tiene un dígito duplicado, refiriéndose el "dos" a una serie de sucesos de déjà vu. El título hace alusión a un razonamiento ilógico y absurdo.

En el libro, Catch-22 es una regla militar que tipifica la operación y el razonamiento burocráticos.

Para el Coronel Cathcart, que deseaba ascender en el escalafón y para ello presiona para que se realicen más misiones mejor, solo los locos harían estarían dispuestos hacer tantas misiones.

El narrador en el libro explica

> Solo había una **trampa** (catch) y era **Catch-22**, que especificaba que la
> preocupación por la seguridad de uno frente a los peligros que eran
> reales e inmediatos era el proceso de una mente racional. Orr estaba
> loco y podía ser castigado. Todo lo que tenía que hacer era preguntar;
> y tan pronto como lo hiciera, ya no estaría loco y tendría que volar
> más misiones. Orr estaría loco por volar a más misiones y estaría cuerdo
> si no lo hiciera, pero si estaba cuerdo, tenía que volar. Si
> volaba, estaba loco y no tenía que hacerlo, pero si no quería, estaba
> cuerdo pero tenía la orden de hacerlo. Yossarian se conmovió profundamente por la
> absoluta simplicidad de esta cláusula de Catch-22 y dejó escapar un
> respetuoso silbido. (pág. 56, cap. 5)

[image]